# Printable prints whole frame instead of content

Tags: java, swing, printing, jframe, bufferedimage

I want to print a BufferedImage, I didn't know how to so I tried printing all contents.
 The code seems to work fine, except for the fact that it also prints the border of the frame and the printbutton, and not just the content as intended. 
Also the quality becomes total shit for some reason.

This is the code I wrote for it:

```
package frik.main;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.print.PageFormat;
import java.awt.print.Printable;
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;
import frik.data.Config;
import frik.utils.ImgUtil;

public class Previewer implements Config, Printable, ActionListener{

    private JFrame Frame;
    private JPanel ImagePanel;
    private JLabel PicLabel;
    private JButton PrintButton;
    private static BufferedImage before;
    private static boolean Scaled;

    public Previewer(BufferedImage Image, boolean scaled){
        this.before = Image;
        this.Scaled = scaled;
        loop();

    }

    public int print(Graphics g, PageFormat pf, int page) throws PrinterException{
        if (page > 0) { 
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
        }
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D)g;
        g2d.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());

        Frame.printAll(g);

        return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
        job.setPrintable(this);
        boolean ok = job.printDialog();
        if (ok) {
            try {
                job.print();
            } catch (PrinterException ex) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The Printjob did not successfully complete.", "Print Failure.", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
    }

    public void loop(){
        UIManager.put("swing.boldMetal", Boolean.FALSE);
        Frame = new JFrame("Mold Preview");
        ImagePanel = new JPanel();
        PrintButton = new JButton("Print Mold");

        Frame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
               public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {System.exit(0);}
            });

        if(Scaled){
            PicLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(ImgUtil.scaleImage(PAPER_WIDTH / 3, PAPER_HEIGHT / 3, before)));
        }else if (!Scaled){
            PicLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(before));
        }

        ImagePanel.setBackground(Color.orange);
        ImagePanel.add(PicLabel);
        Frame.add("Center", ImagePanel);

        PrintButton.addActionListener(this);
        Frame.add("North", PrintButton);

        Frame.pack();
        Frame.setVisible(true);
        Frame.setResizable(false);

    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Previewer(before, Scaled);
        //////////////////////////////
    }
}
```

So if someone could help me print just the BufferedImage, or Just the ImageIcon holding the BufferedImage that would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, to start off, why would you call `Frame.printAll(g)` if you are only concerned about printing the image? Instead of doing that, just try drawing the image:

`g.drawImage(Image, x, y, null);`

Comment: Yeah, It works but for some reason when I do that the outcome of the print is to big for the paper. Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe you should try resizing your image.